# Book recommendation - Linear Algebra and Affine Geometry

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, reference-request, book-recommendation

I really need a good book with some solved exercises about Linear Algebra and Affine Geometry (orthonormal basis, rotations, etc.). I want to understand the algorithms to solve that kind of problems but I can't understand the theory, it's too unclear and I think that some exercises can help me a lot. Thank you!

EDIT: I want a book which present a lot of exercises with complete solutions, especially to prepare for exams and for better understanding

EDIT 2 : I really appreciate if you can recommend a book which contains : system of vectorial equations, rotation of basis, etc. I don't know why, but in general these concepts are missed from the books.

Answer (score 0):

[Linear Algebra and its Applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0155510053)  by Gilbert Strang 
[Geometry](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1107647835) by David A Brannan
 
Also [Jim Hefferon, *Linear Algebra*](http://joshua.smcvt.edu/linearalgebra/). This is a well-known open-source textbook and has lots of good exercises.